# How to run b2sum-amd64-windows command recursively in a batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

BLAKE (hash function): https://blake2.net/

Download: https://blake2.net/b2sum-bin_20130305.zip

The current b2sum-amd64-windows command does not include recursive option

For example in windows command prompt:

C:\Users\Name>b2sum-amd64-windows.exe -a blake2sp "G:\Program Files\Techland\Dying Light*.*"

Could not open `G:\Program Files\Techland\Dying Light\DW': Permission denied
Could not open`G:\Program Files\Techland\Dying Light\DW_DLC1': Permission denied

*message digest* G:\Program Files\Techland\Dying Light\239140_install.vdf

*message digest* G:\Program Files\Techland\Dying Light\bink2w64.dll

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you. I didn't knew the tool.

The errors in the output are caused by the tool trying to open a folder as if it was a file

You will need to iterate over the folder structure calling the tool for the content of each folder

```dos
for /r "G:\Program Files\Techland\Dying Light" /d %a in (.) do b2sum-amd64-windows.exe -a blake2sp "%~fa\*" 2>nul
```

The `for` command will recurse (`/r`) from the indicated point searching for directories (`/d`). For each folder found, the `for` replaceable parameter `%a` will hold a reference to it. Using this reference we will use the full path to the folder (`%~fa`) to execute the tool against the files (and folders, no way to separate them) inside it. The errors are sent to stderr, so we redirect this stream (2) to the nul device to hide them.

To use this command from inside a batch file, the percent signs need to be escaped, replacing each `%` with `%%`, so you end with `%%a` and `%%~fa`